# Unity - Align text in Property Field

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

Is there a way to align text into a property field? I don't mean "label", I mean the text into field.
For example:

```
EditorGUI.PropertyField(fieldPosition, serializedVar, GUIContent.none);
```

I'ld like that value into "serializedVar" would be right aligned not left.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so .. if it is a string you can use a `EditorGUI.TextField` instead which takes an optional `GUIStyle` argument where you can then change the [`alignment`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-alignment.html)

Comment: @derHugo Unluckily I can't know before which type it would be.